# How can the comparison test be used on functions like sine?

Tags: calculus

This problem came up on my most recent test: $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\sin n}{n^4+1}$$ I couldn't even begin to figure out what to compare it to (or what other test to use). It doesn't work to compare it to $\frac{1}{n^4}$ because sine oscillates, and you can't compare it to $\sin n$ because that doesn't have a limit. Can you guys point me in the right direction on what to do here?

Comment: Think a little more intuitively. Yes, $\sin n$ oscillates, but as $n$ gets huge, the terms of your series decay to zero very quickly. What matters for the convergence of a series is how quickly the terms converge to zero. The answers have shown you how to use the comparison test to deduce absolute convergence. You could also use the $\limsup$ version of the [limit comparison test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test).

Answer (score 2):

[If $\displaystyle \sum |a_n|$ converges, then so too does $\displaystyle \sum a_n$](https://www.ima.umn.edu/~miller/1372absconv.pdf).  You can compare $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left| \frac{\sin(n)}{n^4 + 1} \right| = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{|\sin(n)|}{n^4 + 1}$ with $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^4+1}$, which can itself be compared with $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^4}$.

Answer (score 1):

One can use the convergence of the absolute series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^\infty\left|\dfrac{\sin n} {n^4+1}\right|$ to ascertain the convergence of $\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^\infty\dfrac{\sin n} {n^4+1}$.

Since $\left|\dfrac{\sin n} {n^4+1}\right|\le\dfrac{1} {n^4+1}\le\dfrac{1} {n^4}$, the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^\infty\left|\dfrac{\sin n} {n^4+1}\right|$ converges and thus the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^\infty\dfrac{\sin n} {n^4+1}$ also converges.

Answer (score 0):

Estimate absolute values:
$$
|\sin (\mbox{any real number} ) | \leq 1,$$ so
$$
\left|{\sin(n) \over 1 + n^4}\right| \leq {1 \over 1 + n^4} \leq {1 \over n^4}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$|sin \alpha| \leq 1 $ all $\alpha$. thus

$$ \left| \frac{ \sin n }{1 +n^4 } \right| \leq \frac{1}{n^4+1} < \frac{1}{n^4} $$

Since $\sum n^{-4}$ converges, then your series converges